# How to remove an eventlistener from a class?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem removing an event listener. I get a `changeGirl.off("click") is not a function` error when I run this script. I need to remove the event listener, everything else is working perfectly. Any ideas?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $(".changeGirl").each(function() {
  var changeGirl = this;
  
  changeGirl.addEventListener("click",function() {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
     changeGirl.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
     changeGirl.off("click");
    }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","getUsers.php?girls="+$(this).attr("data-position"),true);
   xmlhttp.send();
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: If you use jQuery, why not just do `$(".changeGirl").on("click", …)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to extract the function from your addEventListener and name it for example yourFunction, then use removeEventListener:

```
changeGirl.addEventListener("click", yourFunction);
changeGirl.removeEventListener("click", yourFunction, true);
```

Comment: `unbind` is deprecated and should not be used and there are three different reasons why that code would not work: `changeGirl` is a DOM element object, `unbind` is a method only available on jQuery objects. `unbind` only unbinds event handlers added with jQuery in the first place.

Comment: It worked, thanks, but tried that before, and it didn't work!?! Now it does, so thanks... I must have made som error before...

Comment: If that answers the question, I would suggest accepting the answer to reward the person that helped you and let everyone know you've found the solution.